# No TFS-connection in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

Our project is on Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online) and we are using visual studio 2013, but I dont seem to have any connection from Solution Explorer to Team Services.

I have no problem opening Team Explorer-> Source Control Explorer and Get Latest, but when I open the .sln file in visual studio, it seems disconnected to Team Services in the sense that I cant find menu items like "Get Latest", "Check out" and so on. When I create new items in VS they aren't added to Team Services, I have to add them by using Source Control Explorer.

My mappings seems fine, they point to the folders where I have my source code locally.

So, how to I connect my VS to Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: Does the Team Explorer show the Changes option? Can you see if it has files as untracked/excluded?

Answer (score 0):

Under Source Control Explorer in VS, double click the .sln file, then go to Solution Explorer to check whether the files under the solution is source controlled.

Additionally, you can go to File--Source Control to see whether you can see "Get latest version" or "Check Out for Edit".

Comment: sorry for late response. Im not curently at the computer where I have the problem Ill get back to you as soon  as I get there. Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

Open the <kbd>File</kbd> - <kbd>Source Control</kbd> - <kbd>Manage Source Control</kbd> and click <kbd>Bind</kbd> for each project in the solution.

Also make sure that Team Foundation Server is selected as the version control tools in <kbd>Tools</kbd> - <kbd>Options</kbd> - <kbd>Source Control</kbd>.